# how deep can a url be in angular?

Tags: angular, routes

i'm trying to learn angular's routing basics and I'm fighting with a strange issue.
The problem is that I can't use more than two levels of features to obtain a url like this 'localhost:4200/teams/settings/people'.
People also is a module cause my intent is to configure other child components like 'home','details',...
I don't know if is it possible but I'have configured the last module just like 'teams' and 'settings' but when I navigate to 'localhost:4200/teams/settings/people' the app goes to root position.
I'm thinking about a limit on child features, It is possible?
In angular docs I haven't found any information on this particular case.
app-routing.module.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path:'teams',component:TeamsComponent},
  {path:'**',redirectTo:'easynow',pathMatch:'full'}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

app.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    TeamsModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  exports:[AppRoutingModule],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

teams-routing.module.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path:'teams',component:TeamsComponent,children:[
    {path:'settings',component:SettingsComponent}
  ]}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class TeamsRoutingModule { }
```

teams.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [TeamsComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SettingsModule,
    TeamsRoutingModule
  ],
  exports:[TeamsRoutingModule]
})
export class TeamsModule { }
```

setings-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path:'settings',component:SettingsComponent,children:[
    {path:'people',component:PeopleComponent}
  ]}
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
 })
 export class SettingsRoutingModule { }
```

settings.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [SettingsComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    PeopleModule,
    SettingsRoutingModule
  ],
  exports:[SettingsRoutingModule]
})
export class SettingsModule { }
```

peope-routing.module.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path:'people',component:PeopleComponent,children:[
    
  ]}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class PeopleRoutingModule { }
```

people.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [PeopleComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    PeopleRoutingModule
  ],
  exports:[
    PeopleRoutingModule
  ]
})
export class PeopleModule { }
```

All components looks like this:

```
<p>Component Name</p>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

this is my output (http://localhost:4200/teams/settings):

```
Sitename
teams works!

settings works!
```

when I try to navigate (http://localhost:4200/teams/settings/people) I return to the root component.

EDIT 1:

I didn't understand the routing module well.
Now I understand that when there are routing modules engaged that are not lazy, it is necessary to repeat the path regularly as I was suggested or, if it is lazy, only the last part of the path that is hung on the previous routing module.
However the problem was solved.

Comment: Revisit the [Angular Tutorial for Routing](https://angular.io/guide/router#child-route-configuration) or another [tutorial](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/routing/child_routes).
You only need one RoutingModule with all routes defined.

Comment: I' have read in the first tutorial that you have mentioned that I can use a separate router module for each feature module and, in fact, in that tutorial was adopted this style for crisis-center feature.

Comment: If you make a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) from it I will take a look.

Comment: @DanielHabenicht
https://stackblitz.com/edit/testrouting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to repeat the complete path to the route you want to add in each module (meaning from root on).

To solve your problem you would have to change your `settings.routing.module.ts` to

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { TeamsComponent } from '../teams.component';
import { SettingsComponent } from './settings.component';
import { PeopleComponent } from './people/people.component';


const routes: Routes = [
   {path:'teams',component:TeamsComponent,children:[
  {path:'settings',component:SettingsComponent,children:[
    {path:'people',component:PeopleComponent}
  ]}
  ]}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class SettingsRoutingModule { }
```

Here is the working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/testrouting-32dqnf?file=src/app/teams/settings/settings-routing.module.ts)

In order to not repeat the configuration each time somebody has written [a neat article](https://medium.com/@shairez/angular-routing-a-better-pattern-for-large-scale-apps-f2890c952a18)